# Retrieving filepath reference from subcribe and storing it into firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, firebase-storage

I'm running this script to upload my image upon form submit

```
updateUser(user: User, privateUser: PrivateUser, dob) {
  //store img in storage
  if(this.file){
  var path = `users/${this.userID}/${this.file.name}`
  var ref = this.storage.ref(path);
  this.storage.upload(path, this.file);

    this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL();
    this.refURL =this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => console.log(url) );
    console.log(this.refURL);

  }
}
```

and I'm trying to store the download url to my firebase as a reference point. 
at this point the console is printing out what i want from this line 
`this.refURL =this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => console.log(url) );`
however `console.log(this.refURL);` is returning me a subscriber instead.
How should I get about so I can then store the url value into firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribing to your observable will return the subscription and that is how observable works you subscribe to them to listen to changes and get the value so perform you action subscribe

```
this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => {
this.refURL=url;//or some other action here
})
```

Or convert to `promise` and `await` for response

```
async updateUser(user: User, privateUser: PrivateUser, dob) {
  //store img in storage
  if(this.file){
  var path = `users/${this.userID}/${this.file.name}`
  var ref = this.storage.ref(path);
  this.storage.upload(path, this.file);

    this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL();
    this.refURL= await this.downloadURL.toPromise();
    console.log(this.refURL);

  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxykdu)

Comment: doing this would result in this.refURL being undefined instead

Comment: and why do you think so ? did you try if you put console.log(this.refURL) inside subscribe you will get the value but if you put outside it will be undef because javascript runs async.For that you can use await check updated ans

Comment: okay i got what you meant when saying the value is only avaiable within the asyn, manage to get the value stored when I shifted my function within the subscribe. Thanks!